# Opengl cpp code to run both on windows and mac?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, opengl, if-statement

I want to know if there is any if syntax that can be used to run opengl c++ code on both mac and windows. More specifically, at the starting of the code can I put an if condition that determines whether the code is running on mac (generally xcode) or windows (generally visual c++) and accordingly include the header files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use preprocessor `#ifdef`.

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#ifdef TARGET_OS_MAC

  #include <osx.h>

#endif
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)

  #include <win.h>

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to abstract your system interfaces to use what is appropriate. This could be detected at build-time or you could have MSVC projects in place for Windows builds and Xcode/Makefile projects in place on OS X.

On Win32, I'm sure you know that using the Win32 API is still relevant. On OS X, Carbon is on its way to being unsupported, so your minimal windowing system will have to be implemented using Objective C. Luckily this isn't very difficult and once you have it in place, your main application can execute without concern.

For prototyping, it might be saner to use a framework that is made for this in mind like SDL/GLUT/Qt, etc. For production, you'd get better performance and control with specializing for each target platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you used the standard header files in C/C++ then all you need is to use glut to initialize the OpenGL window and get keyboard/mouse events from the user. GLUt will abstract OS Layer for you.

Here is the link for GLUT for mac (getting started)

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/glut/Introduction/Intro.html

in the previous link you will find (OS Independent)

Here is the GLUT download link:

http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php

You will need to have just two separate project files myProject.xcode and myProject.vcproj all other files should be shared.

**Note:**
Using timers and all other OS related stuff should be avoided and you instead should use the GLUT given functionality.

You will have to link against the appropriate GLUT when building for windows/Linux/mac.